# How to edit file in resources of Spring MVC?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-mvc

I have a project on Spring MVC, The resources folder added to buildpath of Spring.

[Project Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5TVLw.png)

On some UI action i want to edit the file resources/thirdparty/thirdparty.er from the controller.

So here are the code is tried

```
File inputFile = new File("/home/local/<User>/Desktop/workspace/<ProjectName>/WebContent/resources/thirdparty/thirdparty.er");
```

**result** - it worked fine

Instead of absolute path i wanted a relative path so i tried

```
File inputFile = new File("../../<something>/WebContent/resources/thirdparty/thirdparty.er");
```

**result** - it worked fine, but the path was relative to eclipse(base path), as i was executing code in eclipse

To remove eclipse path dependency, i tried

```
File inputFile = new File("/resources/thirdparty/thirdparty.er");
```

**result** - it didnot worked

Later on searching web, i found

```
Resource resource = new ClassPathResource("/thirdparty/thirdparty.ER");
File inputFile = resource.getFile();
```

**result** - it is returning

*/home/local//Desktop/workspace/**.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps**//WEB-INF/classes/thirdparty/thirdparty.er*

which actually isn't the file i want to edit.
Please let me know how this can be done. I donot want any path dependencies on eclipse, server or the system, it sould be completely based on project.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe all you need is

```
Resource resource = resourceLoader.getResource("classpath:/thirdparty/thirdparty.ER");
```

and just autowire the resource loader like that:

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader resourceLoader;
```